# Exchange Server 2010 not able to use ExchangeServiceBinding proxy class in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-8, exchange-server

Presently I am working on application that needs to fetch data from Exchange server 2010. If I add Service reference in Visual studio 2010 using url "https://mail.test.com/ews/exchange.asmx", the service reference is generating "ExchangeServiceBinding" When I look from browser. But I am not able to use it as object. How to proceed with this? And since I am doing this in windows 8 metro and Wp7, I am not able to use managed api dll. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use raw soap calls.
Here are good links to get started
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2011/09/13/soap-test-application.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc500285.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you are not able to do that in Windows Phone 7. You need to create a proxy web service that *can* connect to Exchange and then use that service as a REST endpoint.

Check out the [tutorials by Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/getting-started/exchange-client.aspx) on how to do that, they needed it for their Tasks application.